# Bootstrap 3 popover empty space in a table row

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace, popover

I am trying to make a popping over large image when cursor is above the small image. Somehow when it pops over it creates white space after current table cell. How do I solve this problem?
html code fragment:

```
 <tr>
  <td data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto left" data-trigger="click" data-html="true">
    <img class="img" style="height:36px" src="{if $product->small_image}files/products/{$product->small_image}{else}files/products/noimage.png{/if}" alt="{$product->model|escape}">
    <div class="popover-content1 hide">
      <img style="max-width:250px;max-height:250px" src="files/products/{$product->large_image}">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    ...poduct-name...
  </td>
  <td>
    ...price...
  </td>
</tr>
```

js initialization:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  content: function() {
        return $(this).find('.popover-content1').html();
      }
});
```

Screenshots:
[normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRIw.jpg),
[popover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RGkk.jpg)

Comment: It better if you have a running jsfiddle or codepen example.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my problem by adding div into current table cell and moving this code

```
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto left" data-trigger="click" data-html="true"
```

into created div. Also modified js
from

```
return $(this).find('.popover-content1').html();
```

to

```
return $(this).next('.popover-content1').html();
```

Seems like data-toggle doesn`t work properly with table cells.